# Blender 3.1.2 Can't Save Preferences or Remember Recent Projects?

Tags: customization, error, system, settings

I'm using version 3.1.2 on Windows, and any time I open up the software, it's as if I'm opening it for the first time, every time.  The *Open recent* option is always empty, the saved bookmarks in the file explorer are always gone, and when I try to save preferences (say, after changing hotkeys), I get an error message:

[image]

What's the deal here? How do I fix this?  Previous versions never did this.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration files shouldn't be stored in the standard Blender installation directory, that is you should have no `c:\Program Files\...\3.1\config\` directory.  Instead they should be installed in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\config\` on a Windows system.

You might be able to restore the proper configuration by using the *File* → *Defaults* → *Load Factor Settings* entry; or you might have to reinstall.

Comment: "Should not": except if you made a portable installation

Comment: Not even then.  On windows standard configurations for any application should never go into `C:\Program Files`.  That's the whole point of having `AppData`. I've clarified that that is what I meant by "installation directory".

Answer (score 1):

I found this YouTube helpful
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0xuN09mmyg
This what I did:
[image]